# Supplying a callback to a DelegateCommand?

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

In my Silverlight app, I have a button that is bound to a `ICommand` that does posts some data to a webservice.

Upon completion, I'd like to have the `Command` trigger a callback to the View letting the view know that that specific `Command` has completed (I want the View to close).

Is there a way to pass a callback action to a `DelegateCommand`?

How else can I notify the View that the ViewModel has completed?

Comment: There is no necessity in callbacks. A view can be notified from a view model using an event. Or you can use the `CompositeCommand` class and add additional handler in the constructor of the view where the view model is applied as the data context.

Comment: @Vorrtex:  Sounds more like an answer than a comment.

Comment: Check out Caliburn Micro.  If your view is a dialog or child and it inherits Screen you can issue a try close from the child view model.

Comment: @AnthonyWJones If I have ever used this type of commands - I would post it as answer. But uncertain suggestions I post as comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use couple of different ways to achieve this. One is to inject a view specific service which will perform operations on the User interface layer. The view model will call the specific method on the injected service. One such exampe is demonstrated [here](http://nileshgule.blogspot.com/2011/05/silverlight-use-dialogservice-to.html).

If you don't want to inject view specific services into the view model, then you can expose an event on the view model like CloseWindow. This event will need to be subscribed in your view.xaml.cs file and from the event handler method you can close the view page.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Any communication from the ViewModel to the view should be done, IMHO, through messaging (which is kind of "loosly coupled event" mecanism). So, I think a nice way to do this is to just send a message (you can use the `Messenger` class from [MVVM Light](http://galasoft.ch/mvvm/getstarted/)) from your ViewModel to the view which would close itself. No callback needed.

Hope this helps ;)